# Google Cloud Storage Bucket won't let me share files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to host files on a Google Cloud Bucket. I've used the service before, but now it's acting up on me with a new bucket for a different client.

For some reason, when I click the "Share Publicly" checkbox, it instantly unchecks itself and refuses to share the file.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Update: After more experimentation, I've found that my client's account completely refuses to allow sharing for some unexplained reason. He's entered his billing information and is still on Trial time, but I don't know if that has anything to do with the issue. I've tried creating other buckets and modifying permissions with `GSUTIL` but no luck.

Comment: Tried doing it via the terminal?

Comment: I haven't and, unfortunately, this wouldn't be a good option for my client, who needs the ability to upload arbitrary files to the bucket.

Comment: You only need to change the ACL on the bucket.

Comment: *sigh* I really didn't want to sign my terminal out of my OWN bucket so that I can configure the client bucket. Considering migrating away from google's infrastructure because it's so cumbersome... I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either. The command I ran was `gsutil defacl ch -u allUsers:R gs://<bucket>` It completed successfully, but didn't fix the problem -- all the files in the bucket are still inaccessible. Even by me!

Comment: The `defacl` command only applies to newly created objects in the bucket.  You would need to change the existing acls with a command like `gsutil -m acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://<bucket>/**`.  I suspect the reason that your client can't do this is that they don't have OWNER permission on the objects, so they cannot read or modify the objects' ACLs.